# problmas con los dias de la semana en calendario bootsrap 3

Tags: php, html, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando en un calendario de bootstrap 3 y jquery es una version de Serhioromano que estube modifcando a mi gusto, pero resulta que hay un gran incoveniente, que cuando ingreso una evento el lunes aparece en la colunma del lunes arriba, pero si genero un evento el martes aparece en la columna del martes pero abajo, y asi sucesivamente, y no s que dependa del,horario del evento, porque todos son el mismo horario, cuando en teoria deberia aprecer arriba todos los eventos, el de lunes, el de martes el de miercoles, les paso foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien ya trabajo con ese tipo de calendario y pudo resolver eso?

Trabaja con plantillas y la plantilla de la semana que tiene ese probolema se llama week-day.html

ese es el codigo week-day.html:

```
<% _.each(events, function(event){ %>
<div class="cal-row-fluid">
    <div class="cal-cell<%= event.days%> cal-offset<%= event.start_day %> day-highlight dh-<%= event['class'] %>" data-event-class="<%= event['class'] %>">
        <a href="<%= event.url ? event.url : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>"><%= event.title %></a>
    </div>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

Ya intente renombrar todas las paginas en php pero no funciona el calendario.

Desde ya agradezco a todos la ayuda.

Aca les dejo el link del calendario que estoy trabajando
https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar no se si alguien lo conoce.